# Adding Parameters to a URLClassLoader

Tags: java, swing, awt

Trying to pass parameters to a jar file...

I have them all saved in a HashMap

```
private final HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
Applet loader = (Applet) URLloader.loadClass("client").newInstance();
loader.setStub(this);
loader.init();
loader.start();
```

^That's the code that I have so far, aswell as the

```
public final String getParameter(String name) {
    return parameters.get(name);
}
```

I do have a method posting paramters.

```
    parameters.put("8", "true");
    parameters.put("9", "false");
    parameters.put("6", "302");
    parameters.put("7", "false");
    parameters.put("4", "5");
    parameters.put("5", "WEBSITE HIDDEN");
    parameters.put("2", "0");
    parameters.put("3", "0");
    parameters.put("1", "0");
```

But how do I actually send them off, can't find anything

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - *"Adding Parameters to a URLClassLoader"* reads like nonsense.  I expect you mean add the params to the context or stub of the applet.

Comment: BTW - I am guessing this relates to opening an applet as in your last question.  But I don't like guessing.  Is this related to applets?  If so, add the tag.